# Confusion in definition of union of Indexed family of sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Given $F$ = Family of Indexed sets and $A_i$ are those sets
Given definition is :

$ \cup F =  ( x | \exists A (A \in F \land x \in A )  $

Why this cannot be written as

$ \cup F =  ( x | \exists A (A \in F \rightarrow x \in A )  $

As latter implies that there exists at least one set in $F$ which has $x$ in it

Comment: The latter implies that there exists at least one set $A$ that satisfies [$A\notin F$ or $x\in A$]

Comment: So it means that there exists at least one A such that $ x \in A.  $.

Comment: No, that is not what I said in my comment. Saying that $p$ or $q$ is true is not the same as saying that $q$ is true.

Comment: But A is in F so it makes $x \in A$ true

Comment: What makes you say that $A$ is in $F$? Is $F$ the family of *all* sets then? If it is not then we surely can find a set $A_0$ with $A_0\notin F$ and for that $A_0$ the statement $A_0\in F\to x\in A_0$ is true. Then also the statement $\exists A[A\in F\to x\in A]$ is true. This for every $x$. So  $\{x\mid\exists A[A\in F\to x\in A]\}$ is a collection of sets that contains *every* set $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition $\exists A[A\in F\to x\in A]$ is satisfied for *every* $x$.

Just take some fixed set $A_0$ that satisfies $A_0\notin F$ (such a set always exists).

Then for *every* $x$ the following statement is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth):$$A_0\in F\to x\in A_0$$

To make things more clear observe that the condition can also be written as:$$A_0\notin F\vee x\in A_0$$

---

**edit**:

Let it be that $F$ is collection of sets that does not contain every set.

Further let it be that: $$\mathcal C:=\{x\mid\exists A[A\in F\to x\in A]\}$$

It is our aim to prove that $\mathcal C$ is the collection of *all* sets.

For this let it be that $y$ is some arbitrary set.

It is enough to prove that this arbitrary set satisfies $y\in\mathcal C$.

**Proof**:

Proving that $y\in\mathcal C$ is exactly the same thing as showing that $\exists A[A\in F\to y\in A]$ is a true statement.

When is $\exists A[A\in F\to y\in A]$ a true statement?

If and only if a set $A_0$ can be found such that $A_0\in F\to y\in A_0$ is a true statement.

Can we find such a set? Yes! Just take a set $A_0$ that satisfies $A_0\notin F$.

Then the statement $A_0\in F$ is false so that the statement $A_0\in F\to y\in A_0$ is true.

Proved is now that $y\in\mathcal C$ and we are ready.

---

So $\mathcal C$ is the collection of all sets.

This shows that $\mathcal C$ is *not the same* as the $\{x\mid\exists A[A\in F\text{ and } x\in A\}$.

Comment: I am not sure i understand it fully. What do you mean by for every x ? is this x belongs to family or otherwise ?

Comment: Can you elaborate please ? i think i dont get point

Comment: Do you understand that statement $p\to q$ is a true statement whenever $p$ denotes a false statement? That is the essence. It is applied here taking the false statement $A_0\in F$ for $p$ and taking statement $x\in A_0$ for $q$.

Comment: i see that. ....but how is it related to question ?

Comment: It means that there exists a set $A_0$ such that either it is not in the family or x is in $A_0$

Comment: Which is - preassumed that not every set $A$ is an element of the family - a true statement. And this for every $x$. So for every $x$ it is true that $\exists A[A\notin F\text{ or }x\in A]$ (or equivalently $\exists A[A\in F\to x\in A]$). As I said in the first line of my answer. Do not hesitate to withdraw your acceptance if my answer is not clear enough.

Comment: Okey Thank you.